# Are there any missable achievements in Rise of the Tomb Raider?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

In the last [tomb-raider-2013](/questions/tagged/tomb-raider-2013), I reached the end of the game and ran out of enemies to finish off the last few single-player achievements. Are there any "missable" achievements in *Rise of the Tomb Raider*, such that I would need to restart the game to attempt it again?

Answer (score 3):

At least Paying Respects is missable http://stevivor.com/2015/11/rise-of-the-tomb-raider-paying-respects-achievement-guide/ as well as playing the game on Survivor.

Not sure if you can repeat the intro tomb of Syria either as I'm only 3 hours in.  I restarted though since I missed some.

Comment: Paying Respects is not missable—it's accessible from the mission replay mode

Comment: That is, replay Flooded Archives